# Is there a way to prevent a button to move "down" when I click it?

Tags: html, button, move

When using a HTML `<button>` whenever you press the button it moves a little. A small animation to show it's actually a button.

I'm looking for a way to have it stay exactly the way it is, and force my animation using mouse Events.

I started off just placing an `<img>` and use `mouse events` to swap the picture. This worked fine, except that it has some side effects I can't seem to get rid of. For starters, pictures can be dragged, which just looks odd if just press the button - hold - and decide you want to leave the button. I can turn off "draggable" but then it will show a blue square selection box, which is very unwanted.

My solution was to place it on a `<button>` element instead (with hidden background and border). This solves all the problems, except that it's slightly wiggling to the side. 
I tried disabling it, but that also disables the javascript events.

How can I force a button to stay in place even if it's clicked?

Comment: i am not 100% sure of what the problem is. can't you just use some css to style the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to use another tag than button (for instance span) and manipulate it's behaviour with javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately with <span> the image is draggable again. Is there another element than <button> that prevents dragging?

Comment: Thanks @Flaritus I finally found an elegent solution. I created a div with a background image and this did the trick. Thanks!